fgets & printf print nothing if i replace the '\n'
This is the file:
this
is
a
sample
of
normal
words


when i try to remove the \n i found that the printf print nothing.
this is my c code:
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp;
  char buffer[64];

  fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "File doesn't exist\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  while (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fp) != NULL) {
    if (buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] == '\n') {
      printf(">> 1 >> %s", buffer);  //!!! LINE 18 !!!
      buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
      printf(">> 2 >> %s", buffer);  //!!! LINE 20 !!!
    }
  }

  fclose(fp);
  exit(0);
}

this is the output:
>> 1 >> this
>> 1 >> isis
>> 1 >> as
>> 1 >> sample
>> 1 >> ofmple
>> 1 >> normal
>> 1 >> wordsl

the output of LINE 20 was lost! (in fact i found isis in outputs' line 2 (so wired), but if i comment the LINE 18, the output will completely disappear)
then if i replace the LINE 20 from printf(">> 2 >> %s", buffer); to printf(">> 2 >> %s\n", buffer);
the output become:
>> 1 >> this
>> 2 >> this
>> 1 >> is
>> 2 >> is
>> 1 >> a
>> 2 >> a
>> 1 >> sample
>> 2 >> sample
>> 1 >> of
>> 2 >> of
>> 1 >> normal
>> 2 >> normal
>> 1 >> words
>> 2 >> words

what happen to printf? why if there is no \n the printf print nothing.
Envir info:
WSL: gcc version 11.4.0 (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04)
I found that if i copy this c code to windows and run it in cmd, the output is correct:
>> 1 >> this
>> 2 >> this>> 1 >> is
>> 2 >> is>> 1 >> a
>> 2 >> a>> 1 >> sample
>> 2 >> sample>> 1 >> of
>> 2 >> of>> 1 >> normal
>> 2 >> normal>> 1 >> words
>> 2 >> words

aha? is there some problem in wsl's bash??

i have tried fflush(stdout);

@SupportUkraine
Yes, i am sure. And if i copy this code to windows and run it , the output is correct.  (originally run in gcc version 11.4.0 (WSL Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04))

Your file was edited on Windows and still has \r characters in it. Try and see what happens when you print a string with \r in it, and then another string.

@D yh It seems the system stores in the buffer also the carriage return character cr.

Your input text file is a DOS file whose lines end with the sequence \r\n.  You need to convert it to a standard Unix text file whose lines end in \n, with no \r character.  There are various utilities that will do this, such as dos2unix which you can install.  Sufficiently powerful text editors can also do this.  All you really need to do is strip out all the \r characters from the file.

If you use buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\r\n")] = 0; to remove the line endings it is safe and deals with all variations.

DOS and Windows stores "\r\n" as newline character (it is "\n" in Unix and Linux).
It seems your input file is encoded in DOS format. So you replace "\n", but "\r" remains in string.
When you printf("\r"), it moves cursor to the first column of current line. So you write over first chars of previous printed string.
Actually, this behavior of "\r" is quit usefull in many scenarios. For example we can create simple progressbars in our C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX 1500

int main()
{
  for (int i = 1; i <= MAX; i++) {
    float percent = 100 * i / (float) MAX;
    printf("\r%5.1f%% ", percent);
    for (int p = 0; p < percent/2; p++)
      printf("=");
    fflush(stdout);
    usleep(10000);
  }
  printf(" [DONE] \n");
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

Output is a progress-bar:
 50.0% =========================


i like your ans, you even told me how to utilize this feature. many thanks.
